# libuv threads are executing sequentially in nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, libuv

So I was executing this code to check the number of threads in threadpool created by libuv library -

```
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');
var sleep = require('sleep');
var start = process.hrtime();

var sample_func = function(callback) {
  var i = 0;
  sleep.sleep(1);
  callback();
}
for (var i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
  (function (id) {
    sample_func(function () {
      var end = process.hrtime(start);
      console.log(util.format('sample func %d finished in %ds', id, end[0] + end[1] / 1e9));
    });
  })(i);
}
```

Since libuv creates 4 threads by default in a threadpool and my sample function is asynchronous, I was expecting this output to be printed in my console -

```
sample func 0 finished in 1.003170344s
sample func 1 finished in 1.052704191s
sample func 2 finished in 1.058100525s
sample func 3 finished in 1.060514229s
sample func 4 finished in 2.003446385s
sample func 5 finished in 2.007682862s
```

So the first 4 iterations are run parallely and last 2 have to wait for the first 4 to finish. However what I got was this -

```
sample func 0 finished in 1.00095422s
sample func 1 finished in 2.056155718s
sample func 2 finished in 3.058480649s
sample func 3 finished in 4.061336076s
sample func 4 finished in 5.063556904s
sample func 5 finished in 6.066219487s
```

This means every iteration is being executed one after another taking a total of 6 seconds. Can anybody help me here why this is happening?

PS: I printed process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE value, I got undefined; node version: v12.9.1

Thanks

Comment: `sleep` blocks for a second, synchronously, on each iteration. Not sure about libuv, you'll have to invoke parallel processing some other way (child_process?)

Comment: Node.js uses only one thread for code execution. It uses the same single thread (not a separate thread) for network I/O. It only spins additional threads to handle disk I/O, DNS (which normally does not have nonblocking API) and some crypto functions (because it is calculations, not I/O). Node.js and javascript in the browser is essentially single-threaded. It is asynchronous/evented/non-blocking but is single threaded (you will find in other languages non-blocking code tend to be single-threaded). It can wait in paralled but perform calculations in series

Comment: As far as I understood, all the asynchronous functions are executed by the threads in the threadpool, then callbacks are queued into task queue which are picked up by event loop one by one to be executed in the main thread. Correct me if i am wrong please.

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs Event loop(Implemented by Libuv) runs in a single thread(main thread). Blocking code(in your case sleep()) runs in the main thread. Network, file, and DNS IO operations run asynchronously by Libuv. Nodejs use the following scheme:

> Asynchronous system APIs are used by Node.js whenever possible, but
>   where they do not exist, libuv's thread pool is used to create
>   asynchronous node APIs based on synchronous system APIs. Node.js APIs
>   that use the thread pool are:
>
> - all fs APIs, other than the file watcher APIs and those that are:
> - explicitly synchronous asynchronous crypto APIs such as
>     crypto.pbkdf2(), crypto.scrypt(), crypto.randomBytes(),
>     crypto.randomFill(), crypto.generateKeyPair()
> - dns.lookup() all zlib
>     *APIs, other than those that are explicitly synchronous.

Now coming back to your problem, `sleep.sleep(1);` function block event loop(main thread) for the 1 second as `sleep` documentation says. That's why your function running one by one synchronously.